# How to query the <entry> nodes from an ATOM feed

Tags: php, xpath, rss, atom-feed

I can query the `description` nodes in an **RSS** feed and return a result like this:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$items = $xpath->query('/rss/channel/item/description/..');

foreach($items as $number => $item){}
```

But it returns nothing when I query the `entry` nodes from an **Atom** feed like this (in which I follow the same pattern as RSS's above):

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$items = $xpath->query('/feed/entry/..');

foreach($items as $number => $item){}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no RSS namespace, whereas Atom elements are in the following namespace:

```
http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
```

You can see this by looking at your document's `feed` element, which probably looks something like this:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

You need to register this namespace before querying for elements in it:

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('a', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
```

And then use the chosen namespace prefix in your expression:

```
$items = $xpath->query('/a:feed/a:entry');
```